# how to pass parameter to setInterval milliseconds value?

Tags: javascript

How can i pass the value of an input field so that it will be the interval of the function?

```
function myTasksInProgressNext() {  
    // the value of this is 1 for example;
    var x = parseInt(document.getElementById('txt').value);
    var y = x * 60000;
    window.open('remindInProgress.php','blank', 'width=200, height=200');
}
var t3 = setInterval(function(){myTasksInProgressNext()}, y);
```

is this correct?

Comment: Do you think it will open multiple popups?

Comment: @Amit Grag it will open the window every x minutes

Answer (score 0):

You should define `x` and `y` variables outside the function:

```
var x = parseInt(document.getElementById('txt').value);
var y = x * 60000;

function myTasksInProgressNext() {  
    window.open('remindInProgress.php','blank', 'width=200, height=200');
}

var t3 = setInterval(function () {
    myTasksInProgressNext();
}, y);
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<form id="interval-form">
    <input type="text" name="timeout" value="1000"/>
</form>

<div id="start-btn" onclick="onStartClick()" >START</div>
```

JS:

```
function runThis() {
    /* code */
}

var interval;

function onStartClick() {
    var form = document.getElementById('interval-form');

    var timeout = parseInt(form['timeout'].value, 10);

    interval = setInterval(runThis, timeout)
}
```